# Indian e-Visa "Some error occurred" when submitting last page of application

Tags: visas, india, e-visas

When submitting a completed 30day Indian e-visa form (including already uploaded photo jpg and passport pdf) on the last verification page I get: "Some error occurred" message.

Did anyone solve this?

https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa

I've asked indianvisaonline.gov.in support through email and they claim the page is working fine and to try sending new application.

So I've tried - on another computer with different photo scan, passport pdf generated again - but also get "Some error occurred" on the last verification page.

Tried also calling the support - but no one is picking up the phone.

Thanks a lot for any advices / tips regarding this situation.

Tomasz

Comment: A message "Some error occured" (as opposed to a standard "404 Page Not Found" or "500 System Error" etc.) *should* not happen without any helpful hint to th euser, it *should* be resolvable by technical support, and *should* be accompanied by some identifying information about the incident that might help support in locating the problem. However, the Indian visa site sucks in many ways already when it is working (e.g., you have only 100 chars to list all countries visited in the past ten years). Unfortunately, noone picking up the phone .. figures /rant

Answer (score 4):

The page got fixed on Monday. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different browser it worked for me. Microsoft Edge "Cortana"